# Selecting NoteProperty does not work in some cases

Tags: powershell

I am trying to put an expression in my profile scripts that will tell which script is running. It would be helpful to get this from the `$PROFILE` variable rather than hardcoding the various scope names.

Only the last expression setting `$scope` appears to work as desired. It appears that the `Where-Object` is not selecting only one name. Why do the first two expressions set the `$scope` variable to all four scope names?

```
$scope = $PROFILE |
    Get-Member -Type NoteProperty |
    Where-Object { $_.Definition.EndsWith($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source) } |
    % { $_.Name }
Write-Host $scope

$scope = $PROFILE |
    Get-Member -Type NoteProperty |
    Where-Object { $_.Definition.EndsWith($($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source)) } |
    % { $_.Name }
Write-Host $scope

$s = $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source)
$scope = $PROFILE |
    Get-Member -Type NoteProperty |
    Where-Object { $_.Definition.EndsWith($s) } |
    % { $_.Name }
Write-Host $scope
```

The output shows that only the last expression selects a single name.

```
AllUsersAllHosts AllUsersCurrentHost CurrentUserAllHosts CurrentUserCurrentHost
AllUsersAllHosts AllUsersCurrentHost CurrentUserAllHosts CurrentUserCurrentHost
CurrentUserAllHosts
```

Comment: `$Profile` is just a string that contains a path.. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: _$Profile is just a string that contains a path_ Not exactly. Its a string with multiple noteproperties containing all known profile paths.

Comment: $PROFILE is a string which has additional NoteProperty members. The name of the NoteProperty members tells the scope under which each profile script location is used. Try using `$PROFILE | gm`.

Comment: `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source` is not always defined.  You're better off utilizing `Get-Host` or `$Host`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - What part of `Get-Host` or `$Host` do you suggest will provide any information about the currrently running script?

Comment: It will provide you the console the script is running in which can be used to determine which `$Profile` is being loaded.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - I agree that `$Host.Name` will show the name of the host being run. However, that does not tell which one of the four (4) profile scripts is being run.

Comment: @lit It's exactly what it tells you.  There are more than four scripts, FYI.  Each `CurrentHost` can potentially have 2-3 different `$Profile`s (VSCode, PSISE, PS, etc.)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - There are four (4) profile scripts that are run (if they exist) during each invocation of Powershell. Which member of `$Host` indicates the script currently being run?